# squirrel.windows application doesn't work after setup

Tags: squirrel.windows

I created a wpf application. I wanted to create a single installation file with auto updates, using squirrel.windows. I followed this tutorial:

https://intellitect.com/deploying-app-squirrel/
(and https://intellitect.com/publishing-a-nuget/ which is being referred to. the only change was in using this line : nuget pack HitKli_WpfApp -Prop Platform=x86 -Prop Configuration=Release)

after i completed the setup the app does not work. maybe it doesn't have any files included cause it is only 1700kb? I am really not sure where to start check from. did anyone had this problem?

Comment: You get an error when you run the distributed app? What does the error say?

Comment: yes, the error says that the app has stopped working. I also checked the %LocalAppData%\HitKli_WpfApp folder and  it conatins nothing but the update and app setup files, and a folder with the nuget package and RELEASES file.

Comment: Whats in the event log when the app crashes?

Comment: "Faulting application name: HitKli_WpfApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b044b7d
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504ade
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00014598
Faulting process ID: 0x13ac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3f402b85cdbed
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Dor\AppData\Local\HitKli_WpfApp\app-1.0.0\HitKli_WpfApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: f6389641-5ff5-11e8-bf55-84a6c8565efe
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: "